# Window Size for Mac application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am new to Mac application development using Cocoa. I am confused as to what should be the window/view size. Like in an iOS app we have proper dimensions for small iPod as well as latest iPods. But how to set the size in a Cocoa App.

Also I want to set the deployment target to OS X 10.6, which does not support AutoLayout.

So what would be a good way to resize the windows which should fit every desktop?

Comment: The window size and deployment targets are two different subjects.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of things you need to consider when sizing windows for a display under OS X.

First, there's the size of the display area. You could use

```
NSRect frame = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
```

but that's a bit simplistic because the user may be displaying the Dock, and there's almost always the menu bar displayed as well. So a better way of determining the maximum display area for the Desktop would be:

```
NSRect frame = [[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame];
```

which respects the menu bar and Dock.

As others have pointed out, this rectangle is seldom the most ideal size for a window. Understand too that this rectangle is only a starting point, because your user may have multiple displays, and they contribute to the total area in which a window may be displayed. But when displaying a new window, you always start within this rectangle. Look to `NSScreen`'s documentation to determine this; the methods above will provide a springboard to your understanding.

I don't know how you plan to create and use your window, but for all but the most simple applications, you'll probably use a subclass of NSWindowController with it. If so, it will be your window's delegate. And so there's an important window delegate method that you'll need to implement in it, and it's this:

```
- (NSRect)windowWillUseStandardFrame:(NSWindow *)window defaultFrame:(NSRect)newFrame
```

This is where you determine the 'standard' location and size of your window's frame. It's called by the window when the window is zoomed 'out' to what is called the "standard state" (versus the size the user makes it, the "user state"). In other words, it's the rectangle that best suits the content of your window, yet keeps in mind the rectangle describing the 'safe' area in which you can display it. Unfortunately, I can't tell you exactly how to code it, because it depends entirely on what you're displaying inside your window.

You can see, then, that the definition of 'proper' is something entirely different from that in iOS. Best wishes to you in your endeavors.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think too much like programming for an iOS device. On OS X the user can display multiple windows on the screen next by each other. He may want to do that depending on the task your app has.

You're going to have to design your window so that all objects fit inside. Based on that, you can set a minimum size as well as a maximum size. Consider the smallest screen resolutions are around 1200 x 700 and thus your minimum size shouldn't exceed that.

Before autolayout there existed a "springs & struts" way to define how objects resize or position with a resizing window frame.

I recommend you start laying out your app on aper or with a graphics tool and then see how much space is necessary. If more space than minimum resolution is necessary, you will have to start using scroll views, split views or similar to make the interface working in different window sizes.

A lot of useful information can be taken from [OS X HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html).