# Minimum window size recomandation

Tags: objective-c, macos, window

I am working on OS-X app, and I need advice on the window size.

Before someone to jump and declare this question as duplicate, I have read this post:[Window Size for Mac application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851212/window-size-for-mac-application) but it didn't help me to solve my issue.

My issue is the following. I use NSTableViews to display some of the data. However in some windows, I am getting horizontal scroll bar in the NSTableView due the numbers of the columns.

Things to be worse, the data in some of the columns are not completly visible, you have to resize the column to reveal the complete text in that cell / column.

I am thinking of increasing the initial window size, but I can't decide how much.

My current window size is 1024 x 768. User can make the app full screen, and window can be resized to be larger than this size, but not smaller.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Regards, John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the table, you should set minimum widths for each column. Select each column in the document outline and view the Size inspector. You should also review the Resizing pop-up on the Attributes inspector.

Similarly, you should review the Column Sizing pop-up on the Attributes inspector for the table view itself.

With respect to the window size, I recommend that you use auto layout if you're not already. Apply appropriate constraints to all of the view, ultimately relating them (directly or indirectly) to the window's content view. Then, don't set a minimum size for the window itself. Let the constraints impose an effective minimum (and potentially even maximum) size.

The trick though, is that not all views will have an intrinsic minimum size. For example, the table view itself may not get any narrower than the sum of the minimum widths of its columns, but it's in a scroll view. The scroll view is allowed to get narrower than the table view, resulting in horizontal scrolling. So, you may need to add an explicit minimum width constraint to the scroll view.

Answer (score 1):

If you set constraits for text inside the rows, you may get some horizontal scrolls. But if you set the constraits for the app elements like UITableView to the borders of the app window, you may resolve this issue.